# git rerere does not auto-commit autoupdated merge resolutions

Tags: git, git-rerere

I'm trying to use the shared rerere cache to automate throwaway integration/test branches.

The idea is that the rerere cache should be up to date when the branch is pushed, so that these merges always pass.  However, they don't:

```
>>> git merge --no-ff invoicing
Staged 'analysisrequest.py' using previous resolution.
Staged '__init__.py' using previous resolution.
Auto-merging __init__.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in __init__.py
Auto-merging analysisrequest.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in analysisrequest.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

At this point, rerere has staged the resolutions that it remembered, and no actual conflict exists.  I can run `git commit`, then continue, but my integration-test-build script sees an error.  I've tried adding `--rerere-autoupdate` to the git merge command, but nothing changes.  I have configured the repo to enable and auto-apply rerere matches.

How can I ask git merge to use my previous resolutions and continue without failing if they are sufficient?

Comment: The situation should improve soon with Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017): https://stackoverflow.com/a/45988818/6309

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Even with the `--rerere-autoupdate` flag, `git merge` seems to be reluctant to automatically complete the merge without some human input. Instead, it executes with an error status, and your integration tool refuses to proceed.

I do not know how your automatic merging is happening, namely, whether you can change the Git command that is executed. If you can, then you can execute the following commands.

```bash
git merge --no-ff branch-to-merge --rerere-autoupdate
if [[ $(git rerere diff) ]]
then
    $(exit 1)
else
    git commit --no-edit
fi
```

- `git rerere diff` lists files that need to be resolved after `rerere`.
- `--no-edit` is necessary to prevent opening the commit message editor.
- In case `rerere` was not able to cleanly merge all changes, this statement will still return with an error status and the merge will not be committed.
- The commit message will still contain the conflicting files.
- `exit 1` needs to be inside `$()` unless you want to exit your shell. (Guess how I know this. :-))

Comment: The usual way to avoid `$(exit 1)` is to use the standard UNIX `false` (or `true`) commands