# rebase - automatically continue if rerere resolved all conflicts

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rerere

Git [rerere](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) provides for reuse of previous conflict resolutions during rebase, and can even stage the resolved files by setting `rerere.autoupdate = True` (as detailed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283670/have-git-rerere-automatically-mark-files-as-resolved)).  However, even if all conflicts are resolved and all files staged, I still have to run `git rebase --continue` to continue the rebase operation.

How can I *automatically* continue if `rerere` has resolved all conflicts and staged all changes?

Comment: Another question has a nice answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27513648/259946

Comment: I don't know if @frasertweedale meant the question this way, but I'm using `git rebase -i` in a script (with `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`).  So not automatically continuing/skipping resolved conflicts is a PITA, because either I have to do it manually or emulate the nicety of `if ! git rebase […]; then git rebase --abort; fi` with lots of `git reset`, `git cherry-pick`, etc. and thus lots of opportunities to mess up.

Answer (score 6):

Rebase should use more the rerere-autoupdate from Git 2.14.x/2.15 onward (Q3 2017).

See [commit f826fb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f826fb799ed06f2f9537466f6988bcabd1200ebd), [commit 8d8cb4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d8cb4b047cef546ea80b8224c7b33707f6d6a4c), [commit 6f0e577](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f0e577e46619a15baefc48192abee34451effa5), [commit 9b6d7a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b6d7a6245e3be34a50a94a1174d8aebf5b1a263), [commit 5fb415b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5fb415b57f93330b5ceb743ac36d99da10ac00b1), [commit fd4a3f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd4a3f486d97682a0f42dfc84fe7af742bd76230) (02 Aug 2017) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1016495](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1016495a7190911b37c354f7a985278c51ae6666), 22 Aug 2017)</sup>

That is because now:

> ### `rebase`: honor `--rerere-autoupdate`
>
> Rebase accepts '`--rerere-autoupdate`' as an option but only honors it
>   if '`-m`' is also given.
>   Fix it for a non-interactive rebase by passing on the option to '`git am`' and '`git cherry-pick`'.
>
> ### `rebase -i`: honor `--rerere-autoupdate`
>
> Interactive rebase was ignoring '`--rerere-autoupdate`'.
>   Fix this by reading it appropriate file when restoring the sequencer state for an interactive rebase and passing '`--rerere-autoupdate`' to merge and cherry-pick when rebasing with '`--preserve-merges`'.

Comment: Note that this does not work for `rebase --continue`, i.e. you already need to specify it for the initial rebase command.

Answer (score 3):

No. Rebase or Merge does not automatically provide a provision for auto-commits when conflicts arise. You could understand more about git merge [here](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0512/13748.html) in 'merging' heading. [git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) also does not provide an option for auto commits while rebasing. Note that you could choose not-to commit while merging.