# Bitbucket: Automatically use rerere for Pull Request

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request, git-rerere

I am new to Bitbucket, and I am trying to figure out how I might be able to use rerere for Pull Requests.

As the admin I would like to try to merge in all branches before someone actually tries merging them in with pull requests. If I catch a branch that will cause a merge conflict I can resolve it ahead of time, and save the resolution with rerere. If I could copy my resolutions to the BitBucket server, it theoretically could automatically resolve the conflict.

I have the following issues, though.

- I do not know where BitBucket does the merges
- Even if I did, there is no setting that allows for the automatic committing with rerere. (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003917/git-rerere-does-not-auto-commit-autoupdated-merge-resolutions/27513648#27513648) that will help from the command line)

I am wondering if there is some way to add a hook of some sort to a pull request that can allow me to execute the requisite commands to apply rerere.

Answer (score 2):

`git rerere` is better suited on the local side (you fetching and then merging pull request branches in your local clone)

`git rerere` is not managed by git repo hosting provider (like GitHub or BitBucket), because a pull request is supposed to be merged trivially (fast-forward merge), for the maintainer to quickly integrate the contributions.

If the merge is not trivial, that means the contributor is notified, and has to do a `git fetch` + `git rebase origin/master` in his/her local repo, before pushing again on his/her push request branch.
Then the maintainer is notified (again) and can simply click a button to integrate that revised and updated contribution.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that a Pull Request is only for fast-forward merges. I was not under that impression.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss If you are in charge of maintaining a project, and you receive 10+ pull request per day, believe me, you will get that impression (that you ought to be able to click "merge this pull request" without any work on your part) *very* quickly ;)

Comment: The goal of a merge request is to have no merge conflict in order to increase the odds of it being integrated quickly by the maintainer (because all he/she has to do is to click on a button): https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/#merging-a-pull-request-using-the-github-web-interface

Comment: I have tried, and BitBucket merges successfully even when it is not a fast-forward, as long as there are no conflicts. If we could get BitBucket to consider rerere's then that would make my job even easier.

Comment: I understand, but for rerere to work, you would need to resolve a conflict at least once, and that is a client-side only operation. Hence no rerere on the server side.

Comment: BitBucket creates a new commit for a merge, something that is normally associated with client-side, so theoretically, I could possibly be able to plug in to that process somehow.

Comment: The merge commit is not client or server side dependent: the merge *conflict* resolution is.